# Как можно оптимизировать данный код?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Дело в чем, уже который раз сталкиваюсь с подобными конструкциями в чужом коде (я сам новичок, поэтому может глупый вопрос):

```
           if(i == 0)
            {
                _mov[0] = Vector3Int.forward;
                _mov[1] = Vector3Int.forward * -1;
                _mov[2] = Vector3Int.right;
                _mov[3] = Vector3Int.left;
            }
            else if(i == 1)
            {
                _mov[0] = Vector3Int.left;
                _mov[1] = Vector3Int.right;
                _mov[2] = Vector3Int.forward;
                _mov[3] = Vector3Int.forward * -1;
            }
            else if(i == 2)
            {
                _mov[0] = Vector3Int.forward * -1;
                _mov[1] = Vector3Int.forward;
                _mov[2] = Vector3Int.left;
                _mov[3] = Vector3Int.right;
            }
            else
            {
                _mov[0] = Vector3Int.right;
                _mov[1] = Vector3Int.left;
                _mov[2] = Vector3Int.forward * -1;
                _mov[3] = Vector3Int.forward;
            }
```

Вопрос заключается в том, можно ли это сделать как-то более просто? Вряд-ли же возможна только такая реализация... Заранее спасибо за ответ!!

Comment: Как минимум можно не в каждой строчке в ячейку писать, а в одну строку, типа `_mov = {..., ... ,..., ...}`. Во-вторых нужно вообще понимание что это за `mov` и зачем он нужен. Вполне возможно тут нужен не глупый массив, а объект, и инициализировать данный объект через конструктор. А Все `if`'ы  можно заменить мапой, где ключ - число, значение - объект с заданными параметрами. Далее просто выдёргивать по ключу объект и пользоваться им

Comment: Что такое `i` и зачем здесь массив? Кажется проблема данного кода находится за его пределами.

Comment: @AntonS. спасибо огромное!! все работает и выглядит гораздо лучше!

Comment: @AntonS. посоветовали новичку как нагенерить кучу мусора в `Update` посредством создания сотни массивов в секунду на каждый такой объект на сцене. Браво. Кто-то еще плюсанул этот коммент. Вы чего, друзья, творите то? Новичек конечно остался доволен уменьшением количества буковок в коде и ушел.

Answer (score 1):

Поиграем с поворотами базового вектора forward на нужные углы:

```
for j = 0..3
    an = pi/2 * (i - (j&1)<<1 - (j&2)>>1)
    s,c = sincos(an)
                        [ c -s]
    mov[j] = (fx, fy) * [     ]
                        [ s  c]
```

где fx, fy - компоненты forward вектора

На Python:  https://onlinegdb.com/ZZZDh18TXK
И без тригонометрии:  https://onlinegdb.com/HUl2ZDb6KR

Comment: Решение невероятно красивое =)

Answer (score 1):

Код можно упростить, например, так:

```
var f =  Vector3Int.forward;
var b =  Vector3Int.back;
var r =  Vector3Int.right;
var l =  Vector3Int.left;
(_mov[0], _mov[1], _mov[2], _mov[3]) = i switch
{
    0 => (f, b, r, l),
    1 => (l, r, f, b),
    2 => (b, f, l, r),
    _ => (r, l, b, f),
};
```

Comment: `moves` не нужен, раз уж на то пошло, можно сразу присвоить в тапл

Comment: @aepot - Да. Изменил.

Comment: `forward`, `left`, `right` - это свойства, возвращающие структуру `Vector3Int`, а не `int`.

Comment: `Vector3Int` разве может быть константой?

Comment: @aepot - Изменен на var - спасибо за предложение

Answer (score -2):

Как минимум можно не в каждой строчке в ячейку писать, а в одну строку, типа `_mov = {..., ... ,..., ...}`. Во-вторых нужно вообще понимание что это за `mov` и зачем он нужен. Вполне возможно тут нужен не глупый массив, а объект, и инициализировать данный объект через конструктор. А Все `if`'ы  можно заменить мапой, где ключ - число, значение - объект с заданными параметрами. Далее просто выдёргивать по ключу объект и пользоваться им

Примерная реализация.

Объект

```
class Mover {
    поле1 = null
    поле2 = null
    поле3 = null
    поле4 = null

    конструктор Mover(поле1, поле2, поле3, поле4) {
        присваивание значений
    }
}
```

Мапа

```
Dictionary<int, Mover> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Mover>() { 
    {0, new Mover(..., ..., ..., ...)}, 
    {1, new Mover(..., ..., ..., ...)}, 
    {2, new Mover(..., ..., ..., ...)}, 
    {-1, new Mover(..., ..., ..., ...)}, 
};
```

Далее в коде

```
if (myDictionary.TryGetValue(КЛЮЧ, out value)) {
    
} else {
   myDictionary.TryGetValue(-1, out value);
}
```

Вместо `if`/`else` можно изначально дефолтное значение задать переменной, а потом просто применить `TryGetValue` по ключу. Если получится достать - то значение в переменной изменится, а если нет, то останется дефолтным

типа

```
value =  myDictionary[-1]; // это псевдокод, я не знаю как это выглядит в C#
myDictionary.TryGetValue(КЛЮЧ, out value)
```

Comment: А если внимательней вчитаться в код?

Comment: @aepot вы можете дать свой **правильный** ответ, с учётом внимательного вчитывания в код

Comment: Правильный ответ за пределами показанного кода, я же в комментарии выше написал. Вообще для меня загадка, откуда взялся массив, и как он используется. Если уж на то пошло и данные, сгенерированные подобным образом используются в текущей итерации выполнения кода, например сразу после показангного кода, то проще использовать аллокацию в стеке посредством структуры из 4 векторов. Но я уверен, что даже это будет не самым оптимальным решением.

Comment: Про словари: _Далее в коде_ - при попадании в дефолтное значение запрос к словарю идет дважды, что не есть хорошо для перфа. _типа_ - вторая строчка кода перезапишет `value` в любом случае, то есть первая не даст результат никогда, хотя синтаксически написана верно. Можно было бы использовать что-то типа `if (!dict.TGV(x, out var value)) value = <default>;`. Тогда при промахе просто в value попадет дефолтное значение, при этом в пользу производительности его можно не класть в словарь, а положить в отдельное поле, если это ссылка, либо создать на месте, если структура.

Comment: @aepot читайте внимательно, я писал что это псевдо код. При таких комментариях можно докапаться и до поле1 поле2 и т.д. Тут описан общий подход, а не точная реализация для копипасты

Comment: Я увидел комментарий. И дал совет, не надо воспринимать попытку помочь оформить точнее ответ с конкретным примером как мусорную критику.

Comment: окей. просто он не имеет смысла.

Comment: Вариант со словарем неплох. В этом ответе плохое только первое предложение. Вот оно намусорит, остальное имеет право на жизнь.

Comment: ок) *(ещё 12 символов)*